# Magento 2 Hide usps shipping method in frontend

Tags: magento2, module, shipping, usps

I've done it fine in Magento 1, and in the offline shipping methods, but I can't figure out how to hide usps and ups.  Not sure which model to even modify to do it currently trying the following:

```
namespace MasonStedman\PaymentRestriction\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession;
use Magento\OfflinePayments\Model\Cashondelivery;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Helper\Carrier as CarrierHelper;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Framework\Xml\Security;

class Carrier extends \Magento\Usps\Model\Carrier
{

    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->canCollectRates()) {
            return $this->getErrorMessage();
        }
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
        $this->setRequest($request);
        $this->_result = $this->_getQuotes();
        $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);

        if ($this->backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $this->getResult();
        }

        $isLogged = $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
        if (!$isLogged) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In backend go to Stores > configuration > shipping methods and disable the two methods there. Save and flush the cache.

Comment: That simply disables the shipping method.  I need it enabled in the backend and disabled in the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using a plugin. The plugin is declared in the `Your/Module/etc/di.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Usps\Model\Carrier">
        <plugin name="hidePlug" type="Your\Module\Plugin\Hide"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Now for the plugin class - `Your\Module\Plugin\Hide`

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Plugin;


use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session;

class Hide
{
    protected $backendSession;

    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->backendSession = $session;
    }

    public function aroundCanCollectRates($subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        if ($this->backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $proceed();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This will cause the USPS shipping method to not show on frontend, but it will still be available in the backend.