# disable fedex shipping method before minimum cart amount 50 in magento2

Tags: magento2

I want minimum order amount 50. I have to enable free shipping and FedEx.

I have configured as:

```
System >> configuration >> Sales >> Minimum order amount >> Yes
```

but default Magento minimum order amount doesn't  work.

How to set minimum order amount 50?

Please give me any solution!

Comment: similar thread https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151727/magento-2-hide-usps-shipping-method-in-frontend/152992

Comment: its not working  @magento two